# Статьи и видеоматериалы по работе с Android SDK

Tags: android-sdk, android

Всем привет, хочу начать программировать под Android. Прочитал много инструкций об установке в связке Eclipse+Android SDK. После того как поставил Eclipse, скачал Android SDK, так там вроде Eclipse уже есть, и с ним можно работать, запускать проекты. Как правильно лучше все сделать? Подкиньте еще, пожалуйста, пару ссылок на полезные статьи и если есть видеоуроки или лекции по материалу.

Comment: Можно использовать и тот eclipse, который идет вместе с sdk. Он уже настроен.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, подскажите пожалуйста еще полезные материалы по теме.

Comment: не знаю. я в таких случаях пишу в гугл "пишем под андроид"(или типа того) и читаю, пробую писать первое приложение. Затем второе, третье, четвертое, over9000. Чем больше пишешь тем больше проблем появляется тем больше проблем ты решаешь(если голова есть) тем лучше ты разбираешься в этой теме. Так что гугл самый лучший документ по этой теме.

Comment: Да мусора многовато, так пару доков уже отобрал, опыт программирования есть но под другие языки, а тут слишком много инфы пока, автоматом нужное не отберешь, поэтому стараюсь есть небольшой вилочкой, чтобы не подавиться. А вот если пару людей в теме и которые уже кое-что знают все равно могут дать материал, по которому они учились и который им реально помог. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: [StartAndroid][1]


  [1]: http://startandroid.ru/ru/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Уроки на английском](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

> Тренинг для разработчиков Android. Вы найдете набор уроков в классах, которые описывают, как выполнить определенную задачу с примерами кода, которые можно повторно использовать в своем приложении. Занятия организованы в несколько групп.